# MSDN - ReadDirectoryChangesW does not recurse

Tags: c++, msdn, readdirectorychangesw

I'm running **ReadDirectoryChangesW** from within a thread in my C++ program. Unfortunately I only get notifications when the files from the root directory are changed, even though I've set the bWatchSubtree argument to TRUE.

The docs say:
**bWatchSubtree** [in]
*If this parameter is TRUE, the function monitors the directory tree rooted at the specified directory. If this parameter is FALSE, the function monitors only the directory specified by the hDirectory parameter.*

What am I missing?
Thanks!
kk

```
void WatchDirectory(LPTSTR lpDir)
{
    HANDLE hDir = CreateFile(
        lpDir,
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
        NULL
    );

    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION strFileNotifyInfo[1024];
    DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;

    while(RUNNING)
    {
        if(ReadDirectoryChangesW(
            hDir,
            (LPVOID)&strFileNotifyInfo,
            sizeof(strFileNotifyInfo),
            TRUE,
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
            &dwBytesReturned,
            NULL,
            NULL) == 0)
        {
            MGlobal::displayInfo("Error Reading Directory Change");
        }
        else
        {
            // Do cool stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tough to say without seeing your code or knowing anything about the underlying file system and its permissions.

Comment: Thanks @MrEricSir, the code is standard for this kind of operation I presume, I simply call ReadDirectoryChangesW in an infinite loop. If it returns something else than 0 I call another function.
The question in this case seems to be what can prevent Windows from recursing from the root directory?
The root directory is on the network, but I get similar issues with a local directory too. Other than that there's nothing special here. I'll add my snippet anyway.